# Is there a way to mathematically prove that $Ax<b$ exists when you have a certificate of infeasibility?

Tags: optimization, proof-writing, linear-programming

I have the following practice problem:

Let A be an m×n matrix and let b be a vector with m entries. Prove or
disprove each of the following statements (y is a vector with m
entries):

(i) If there exists y such that $y^TA ≥ \vec{0}$ and $ b^Ty < \vec{0}$ , then $ Ax ≤ b, x ≥ \vec{0}$ has no
solution.

I believe that the hypothesis satisfies the definition of a certificate of infeasibility and that $Ax \neq b$ for all $x\geq\vec{0}$, but I dont see why there can't exist an $Ax<b$ where $x>\vec{0}$ since such an x would not be a feasible solution and so the certificate of infeasibility doesn't say anything about it.

That was just my initial thought process, let me know if it's true and how I could go about writing the proof if so.

Edit: Would this be a valid counter-example?

Let y = -1, A = (-1,-2,-3),b = 10.

This satisfies the hypothesis:

$yA = (1,2,3) \geq \vec{0}$

$by = -10 < 0$

But consider $\bar{x} = (1,1,1)$ where $\bar{x} \geq \vec{0}$ and $A\bar{x} < b$ since $ 6<10$